# Styling a checkbox in a ReactJS environment

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, checkbox

I'm trying to style a checkbox in a **ReactJS** environment for IE11, but don't seem to be having much success. Can anyone please advise? The code is as follows:

CSS:

```
 .squared  {
      input[type=checkbox] {
        border-radius: 4px;
        background: #ff0000;
        width:100px;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<Col numCol={2} className="col-w-select squared">
  <input style={{float: 'left', borderColor: 'red', border: '3px'}} type="checkbox" checked={isChecked} /> <span className={(String(currentlyClicked) !== String(item[idField])) ? 'l-collapse-icon' : 'l-expand-icon'}>&nbsp;</span>
</Col>
```

> Please note that applying styling attributes within the input tag
>   itself seems to have no affect!?

Thanks

Comment: 1. CSS syntax doesn't support nesting. Do you use a preprocessor like LESS/SASS? 2. The inline styling should work, BUT shorthand `border` overwrites `borderColor`, and applying a border to checkbox may indeed have no effect. `float` works fine though. This doesn't have much to do with React, the effect would be the same in pure HTML+CSS as well.

Comment: @jnoweb, was my answer of any use to you? If so, please consider marking it as "accepted".

Answer (score 19):

The environment is basically irrelevant here for just styling elements with CSS.
The *real* problem here is that you are trying to style a checkbox which doesn't really work in browsers.

Here's what the [MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Advanced_styling_for_HTML_forms#Check_boxes_and_radio_buttons) about this:

> Styling a check box or a radio button by itself is kind of messy. For example, the sizes of check boxes and radio buttons are not really meant to be changed, and browsers can react very differently if you try to do it.

A workaround to this is to create a "fake" checkbox and style it the way you want, while hiding the "real" one.

Below is an implementation I use in my project. The MSN link above provides some alternative (CSS) solutions as well...

```js
var Demo = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {isChecked: false};
  },
  
  toggleCheck() {
    this.setState({isChecked: !this.state.isChecked});
  },
  
  render: function() {
    return (
      <span onClick={this.toggleCheck}>
        <input type="checkbox" checked={this.state.isChecked} />
        <span></span>
      </span>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Demo />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}
input[type="checkbox"] + span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: -1px;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  margin: -1px 0px 0 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: white left top no-repeat;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + span {
  background: #D9534F -19px top no-repeat;
}

input[type="checkbox"] + span {
  margin-right: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

---

If you are using [react-bootstrap](/questions/tagged/react-bootstrap), just replace the JSX bit above with this:

```
<Checkbox onChange={this.toggleCheck} checked={this.toggleCheck} inline>
  <span></span>
</Checkbox>
```

Good luck.

Comment: Amazing however, I am unable to get the `e.target.name` or `e.target.id` while listening to an `onChange` event. It returns undefined as the input is not in the DOM. So what do we do in that case?

Answer (score 7):

Just add this code to your CSS, and you will be able to style your checkbox!

```
input[type=checkbox] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    /* create custom checkbox appearance */
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    padding: 6px;
    /* background-color only for content */
    background-clip: content-box;
    border: 1.5px solid #bbbbbb;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background-color: #e7e6e7;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;

    &:checked{
        background-color: #ff0000;
    }

    &:focus{
        outline: none !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following @[Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2030321/chris) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42627468/1787312) I've changed a bit the styles to suit my needs, sharing in case anyone else is looking for something like it. Haven't tested it in IE11.

Thanks!

```js
var Demo = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {isChecked: false};
  },
  
  toggleCheck() {
    this.setState({isChecked: !this.state.isChecked});
  },
  
  render: function() {
    return (
      <span className="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" checked={this.state.isChecked} />
        <span className="wrapper" onClick={this.toggleCheck}>
            <span className="knob"></span>
        </span>
      </span>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Demo />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```css
.checkbox input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}
.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .wrapper {
    background-color: #8cde95;
}
.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .wrapper .knob {
    left: 20px;
}
.checkbox .wrapper {
    background-color: #666;
    border: 1px solid #666;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 42px;
    height: 20px;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
}
.checkbox .knob {
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid #666;
    border-radius: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 2px;
    position: relative;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    left: 0;
    transition: left 100ms ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```